# Unable to use java.lang.reflect.Field.modifiers in Java 11

Tags: java, reflection, java-11

Recently passed from Java 9 to Java 11 where the code below used to work fine :

```
        final Field a = bb.class.getDeclaredField("a");
        a.setAccessible(true);
        final Field b = bb.class.getDeclaredField("b");
        b.setAccessible(true);
        final Field modifersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifersField.setInt(a, ~Modifier.FINAL & a.getModifiers());
        modifersField.setInt(b, ~Modifier.FINAL & b.getModifiers());
        a.set(null, BigInteger.valueOf(5));
        b.set(null, BigInteger.valueOf(5));
        modifersField.setAccessible(false);
```

But in Java 11 i get this error :

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private int java.lang.reflect.Field.modifiers accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang.reflect" to module
```

I tried added VM Parameters like :

```
--add-exports
java.base/java.lang.reflect=com.goxr3plus.applicationName
```

But again nothing ... just a warning and application crashes :

```
WARNING: package java.lang.reflect not in javafx.base
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: the linked two answers, explain the same thing

Comment: The java.lang.reflect package is in java.base, not javafx.base. In any case, hacking the private/undocumented Field.modifiers field is horrible and no guarantee that it won't break at any time (JDK 12 at least).

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  It should not be necessary to violate encapsulation by modifying private or final fields.

Comment: @VGR I need to do it , really . I don't understand why Java 11 removed this important concept .

Comment: As I said:  encapsulation.  Private members are private for a reason.  They constitute the internal implementation of a class, which can change at any time.  The class’s responsibility is to provide a result according to each method’s contract.  How it does that is the class’s own business.

Comment: I got this in an Android project. Updating all my test dependencies (powermock etc.) resolved the issue.